# linking multiple queues to same service in SQL service broker

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, service-broker

Hi Everyone,
            I have just started working with SQL service broker. I was wondering if we can **link two service broker queues to same service** such that when a message is sent using that service, it will be delivered to both queues i.e both the queues will contain same copy of a message. Is there any way like this or there is some other way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Pankaj

Answer (score 2):

No, in SQL 2008, service broker only supports DIALOG conversations, not MONOLOG, meaning there can be only one endpoint.

Comment: Ok Thank you very much for the reply..!! Can you suggest any other way to do this? Actually I want make a backup queue which will store all the messages in original queue. This will help in monitoring the original queue.

Comment: You could perhaps create a table that matches the schema and use a trigger on the queue

Comment: @PeteCarter  How about the later versions of sql server , do they support multiple end points. This is very important for me to trigger two stored procedures from a single point for parallel processing.